# Restoring file history on a moved folder in git using a previous commit

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have a git repository in which all of the files were moved from one folder to another. This caused *all* of the history to be lost (this was a number of commits ago).

I can see the history of these files using

```
 git log --follow
```

but would like the history to appear as 'normal'.

I realise that I cannot 'restore' the history of these files as git treated the move as a *delete* and an *add*, and there are many StackOverflow answers to that affect.

I was wondering, however, if a workflow (perhaps involving branching from an old commit) existed that would allow me to restore the history?

I was thinking something along the lines of this (although I cannot get this exact process to work without many conflicts on the last step):

1. Checkout a commit prior to the move
2. Branch from this commit and move the files properly using `git mv`
3. Merge/fast forward this branch to the current tip of master

Is anything like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not too far back in the history, you could check out a commit and instead of renaming the folder use the following command:

`git mv oldDirectoryName newDirectoryName` which would preserve the history and apply the changes manually.

About the third point I have not tried anything like that, but a thread on stackoverflow actually deals with a similar issu